# JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) On IE browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

My Automation scripts are getting braked on IE 11 Browser and getting this error while executing the script on multiple forks.

Please help

Comment: That error message can be caused by many different things. You should provide the full error with stack trace, as well as your scenario - what did you do so that you got that error message